# Get list.files to read in a list of files in the same order as Windows

Tags: r, windows

Is there a way to list files in R as it is listed in Windows when sorted by "Name"?

For instance, say I have a Directory (henceforth "testDir") that has the following files:

```
Slide1_1.txt
Slide1_2.txt
Slide1_3.txt
Slide1_11.txt
Slide1_111.txt
Slide2_1.txt
Slide3_1.txt
```

If I do the following in R:

```
testFiles = list.files(path = testDir, full.names = F)
```

testFiles will have the following output:

```
> testFiles
"Slide1_1.txt"   "Slide1_11.txt"  "Slide1_111.txt" "Slide1_2.txt"   "Slide1_3.txt"  "Slide2_1.txt"   "Slide3_1.txt"
```

However, I would like it to be orderer as such:

```
"Slide1_1.txt"   "Slide1_2.txt"   "Slide1_3.txt"  "Slide1_11.txt"  "Slide1_111.txt" "Slide2_1.txt"   "Slide3_1.txt"
```

Is there another way of reading in these files? It should be noted that the timestamp for these files are not in any specific order.

EDIT: Added additional conditions to filenames

Comment: `testFiles[order(nchar(testFiles))]`

Comment: Or `library(gtools); mixedsort(testFiles)`

Comment: I should expand, the file names I'm specifically using are as such: Slide1_1, Slide1_2, Slide1_3, Slide1_11, Slide1_111, Slide2_1, Slide3_1. I will edit my main post to add additional details.

Comment: Anyone know how to edit a post? :) - Nevermind, found it

Comment: looks like mixedsort works with the additional filenames. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(gtools)
mixedsort(testFiles)
#[1] "Slide1_1.txt"   "Slide1_2.txt"   "Slide1_3.txt"   "Slide1_11.txt" 
#[5] "Slide1_111.txt" "Slide2_1.txt"   "Slide3_1.txt"
```

Comment: @JCB No problem, In case you need the order, there is `mixedorder`